# Create a new column with some inherent conditions

Tags: r

I would like to create a column called `Weight`, which would be as follows:

`Weight = Mode + (constant * mean)`.

`Mode` is column of my `database`.

`Constant` is alternative/total alternatives, in this case will be 0,1, because 1/10.

`Mean` is the average of the values ​​corresponding to a specific alternative. For example, the `mean` for `alternative 10` is (3 + 2 + 2 + 3)/4 = 2,5.

Making an example for alternative 10 then. The weight would be 2 + (0,1.2,5) = 2,25.

```
database<-structure(list(Alternatives = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12), Method1 = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L), Method2 = c(1L, 
8L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Method3 = c(1L, 10L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), Method4 = c(1L, 9L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 
8L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L), Mode = c(1, 10, 6, 7, 9, 6, 4, 2, 3, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L))

   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4 Mode
1             3       1       1       1       1    1
2             4      10       8      10       9   10
3             5       7       6       7       6    6
4             6       8       7       8       7    7
5             7       9      10       9      10    9
6             8       6       9       6       8    6
7             9       5       4       4       5    4
8            10       3       2       2       3    2
9            11       4       3       3       4    3
10           12       2       5       5       2    2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your constant equals 0.1 , then try

```
database |> mutate(Weight = Mode +
.1 * ((Method1 + Method2 + Method3 + Method4) / 4))
```

- Output

```
   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4 Mode Weight
1             3       1       1       1       1    1  1.100
2             4      10       8      10       9   10 10.925
3             5       7       6       7       6    6  6.650
4             6       8       7       8       7    7  7.750
5             7       9      10       9      10    9  9.950
6             8       6       9       6       8    6  6.725
7             9       5       4       4       5    4  4.450
8            10       3       2       2       3    2  2.250
9            11       4       3       3       4    3  3.350
10           12       2       5       5       2    2  2.350
```

if it is the probability then change it to

```
database |> mutate(Weight = Mode +
1/ nrow(database) * ((Method1 + Method2 + Method3 + Method4) / 4)) |>
 mutate(rank = rank(Weight))
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much! One more thing, you would know how to insert a rank column that considers this column `Weight` that you created. The lower the value in `Weight` , the better the rank position, that is, alternative 3 would be the first in the rank.

Comment: Try the last update if it will help

Answer (score 0):

This can also be accomplished using the base package.

```
database$Weight = .1 * (database$Method1 + database$Method2 + database$Method3 + database$Method4)/4 + database$Mode
database
#   Alternatives Method1 Method2 Method3 Method4 Mode Weight
#1             3       1       1       1       1    1  1.100
#2             4      10       8      10       9   10 10.925
#3             5       7       6       7       6    6  6.650
#4             6       8       7       8       7    7  7.750
#5             7       9      10       9      10    9  9.950
#6             8       6       9       6       8    6  6.725
#7             9       5       4       4       5    4  4.450
#8            10       3       2       2       3    2  2.250
#9            11       4       3       3       4    3  3.350
#10           12       2       5       5       2    2  2.350
```

One can also use the rank function on the resulting "weight" column.

```
database$weight = rank(database$weight)
```

Additionally, the `with` function can be used for convenience:

```
database$weight = with(database, .1*(Method1 + Method2 + Method3 + Method4)/4 + Mode)
```